# How can I add a page break in such a way that it bumps up page-anchored images?

Tags: libreoffice

I have lots of images on lots of pages that are all page-anchored.  I want to insert a page before them all.  But inserting a regular page break doesn't do it.  It just bumps up the text, not the page-anchored images. Is this possible?

Comment: Isn't that the point of having the images page anchored? See https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/61194/how-to-move-all-page-anchored-images-when-adding-new-empty-page-at-the-top/

Comment: The images are large and should be positioned relative to the page. But my question remains. How can I bump them all up?

Comment: You can move the images by hand to the new page or change the anchor to "paragraph" or "character", so they move with the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, it's not recommended to anchor images to the page. Instead, *anchor* to a paragraph and then *position* the image on the page.

Page-anchored images are fixed to a particular page, or you may think of it as a particular page number and the numbering does not change. This behavior has been [reported as a bug](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89477). However, according to Mike Kaganski (a LO developer), it is not a bug but is intended behavior.

Similar questions are on ask.libreoffice.org, all with the same conclusion:

- https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/201131/anchor-to-page/
- https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/65057/photos-and-anchor-to-page/

Comment: I went through all the images on every page and changed the anchor to paragraph.  I can still position them on the page, which I didn't think I could. Thanks for the clarification between anchoring and positioning.